# Detecting embedded blob regions in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

[image]

I am having issues in finding blob regions (marked in red) in above mentioned image(originar).

As of now i can think of two solution

**1. Use SimpleBlobDetector (opencv) to find blob regions**
The opencv SimpleBlobDetector is good for detecting blob regions that are disconnected or isolated, but it fails when the regions are attached like the one in image

**2. Write custom code to detect pattern by iterating pixel by pixel**
This solution will surely solve problem, but will involve a lot of math and also processing time will increase dramatically, so this would be last approach.

Does anyone knows a way of solving this kind of problem, possible solution could be

- Built in functions (opencv)
- Any algorithm

Comment: You can take the distance transform, and then threshold the result image if you know the size of the blobs you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried any morphology at all? Perhaps a few iterations of a morphological open? If your blobs are thick enough, you can also try eroding a few iterations and then running connectivity/blob analysis on the result.

Comment: Well the use case im having, morpholgical operation are not a good choice, as the thickness of lines could vary from sample to sample, as well  the morphological operation will result in information loss.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it, but perhaps you can try to find a way to calculate estimated radius of the blob and then isolate that from the image to be processed again so it won't count connected blobs as one.

OpenCV Docu says:

> From the groups, estimate final centers of blobs and their radiuses and return as locations and sizes of keypoints.

Expensive but perhaps worth a shot. OpenCV does various filtration with SimpleBlobDetector, I think there's one for circularity. You can take advantage of it.

Comment: Thanks,  i tried using blob algorithm of opencv, problem is as i stated it will only find isolated blobs, In simple terms when working with image like above it will not detect any blob at all because the whole image in T shape      and not a blob

Comment: Oh right, sorry I was confused. How about detected closed contours? Like if these blobs are connected then they must have a closed irregular shape. But if that also does not work, then perhaps you can just write custom code. Good luck

Comment: the above image is a single contour, so it is not further breakable. Sure the whole image will have a irregular shape, but the issue is not to find whether the the whole image is irregular or not, but to find these small regions which are like blob present in that contour.